# C++ Pointer to Class

Tags: c++

I have a problem for calling the method of library "gum" in my program:

```
gum::BayesNet<double> *myBayNet=new gum::BayesNet<double>;
gum::DiscrereVariable* DV=new gum::DiscretizedVariable<double>;
int main()
{
  // error: invalid declaration
  // of 'gum::BayesNet<duoble>::add' & //forbids declaration of 'DV' 
  unsigned int gum::BayesNet<duoble>::add(const (*DV) str) 
  {
    return (*myBayNet).add(str);
  }
}
```

(See error message in comment.)

Comment: ...and the problem is...what?

Comment: I REALLY hope that the error is not the double misspelled... it's DOUBLE, not DUOBLE

Comment: @BrianKelly: The error message is in a commend in the code.

Comment: the arguments (inputs) of add (const (*DV) str) is a class in DiscrereVariable. how can I define these inputs?

Comment: You urgently need a (better) [C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/), Shahram. That code is awful — and I'm not referring to the syntax error of defining a member function in `main()`. Why are you using globals? Why are you allocating them dynamically?

Comment: gum::DiscreteVariable* DV=new gum::DiscreteVariable;                               template<typename> gum::BayNet<double> *myBayNet=new gum::BayNet<double>;                                                                              unsigned int template<double> gum::BayNet<double>::add(const (*DV)) {int str;return (*myBayNet).add(str);}

Comment: gum::DiscreteVariable* DV=new gum::DiscreteVariable;template<typename> gum::BayNet<double> *myBayNet=new gum::BayNet<double>;                                                                              unsigned int template<double> gum::BayNet<double>::add(const (*DV)) {int str;return (*myBayNet).add(str);}

Comment: can not allocate an object of abstract type gum::DiscreteVariable because des following virtual function are pure within DiscreteVariable...gum::DiscreteVariable::DoamneSize()

Answer (score 2):

DAFUQ is that `const (*DV) str`? `DV` is a variable and you are trying to use it as a typename. Also instead of writing `(*myBayNet).add(str)` simpler (and shorter) way is to write `myBayNet->add(str)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not *calling* a method, your are *defining* it. However, you must not define member functions within `main()` or any other function scope. They must be defined at namespace scope.